# Cómo usar la caja de texto flotante de stackoverflow?

Tags: html

Cómo utilizar en mi web la misma (o similar) caja de texto flotante que aparece cuando pasamos el mouse por encima de, por ejemplo, nuestras medallas.

Me refiero a esto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

He googleado bastante pero solo he dado con referencias a propiedades float de css por ejemplo.

Si me pudieran dar alguna referencia de cómo buscar, estaría muy agradecido, tal vez estoy buscando mal pues no sé con certeza si esto que busco se llama "caja flotante" o "caja de texto flotante".

Comment: ¿Te refieres a mostrar un "tooltip"?

Comment: sii! gracias ahora aparecen mejores resultados en google :D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Esto lo puedes realizar con el atributo `title`. Pasa por encima del texto para ver el título.

Ejemplo:

```html
<p title="Título"> Aqui hay un título </p>
```

Comment: Esto era exactamente lo que buscaba, qué simple!

Answer (score 2):

A lo que te refieres es una información relacionada al elemento.

Con el atributo `title` puedes relacionar con un texto la información que pertenece al elemento.

[+ info sobre el atributo title en Mozilla Foundation](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTML/Atributos_Globales/title)

Te dejo algunos ejemplos como usar el atributo `title`:

```html
<a href="#" title="Pincha me">Un link</a>
<p title="Este texto es muy importante">Un texto</p>
<button title="No te olvides rellenar el documento">Enviar Documento</button>
```

También puedes usar el plugin de [jQuery UI](https://jqueryui.com/tooltip/) para dar estilo al atributo `title` si lo deseas.

[Ver demo](http://jsbin.com/bevoga/edit?html,js,output)